# googletest: How can I include all of my tests in one executable?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using the google test framework for C++.  Following the documentation and examples, I end up with a separate executable for every test ".cc" file that I create.  Is there a way to create a single executable that will call all of my unit tests?

I would like to put my project in a CI tool that reports on test status, so I would like to have a single XML input file instead of many.

The meat of my make file looks like this:

```
class1_unittest.o : $(USER_TEST_DIR)/class1_unittest.cc $(USER_DIR)/class1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_TEST_DIR)/class1_unittest.cc

class1_unittest : class1.o day.o class1_unittest.o gtest_main.a
     $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -pthread $^ -o $(PROJECT_BIN)/$@

class2_unittest.o : $(USER_TEST_DIR)/class2_unittest.cc $(USER_DIR)/class2.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_TEST_DIR)/class2_unittest.cc

class2_unittest : class2.o day.o class2_unittest.o gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -pthread $^ -o $(PROJECT_BIN)/$@
```

Comment: Do you define `main` lots of times? Just define it once, and link together all the `.cc` files.

Comment: I don't have a main in either of my test files.  If I put one in, and call "RUN_ALL_TESTS()," how can I link the cc files together in my make file?  It's not like they have classes in each other to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include all your test files in a single target in your Makefile, and define `main()`, either in one of the test files or in a separate main.cc which will need to be included in the target also.

As the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Primer#Invoking_the_Tests) explain, the various versions of the `TEST()` macro implicitly register their tests with Google Test.  This means that you then can have a standalone main.cc which only contains:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```